Userform ComboBox dropdown list from multiple ranges
I have a userform where a ComboBox should already be populated with values from three different excel worksheets. I have no trouble creating a dropdown list using the .List property of the combobox when it is one range, but this has me completely stumped.
A few of my various attempts below:
Private Sub Userform_Initialize 
Dim A as Variant
Dim B as Variant
A = Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A:A")
B = Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A:A")
With ComboBox1
ComboBox1.List = A + B
End With
End Sub

This generates a type mismatch error
ComboBox1.List = Array(A, B)

This generates an empty dropdown list
I have also tried defining A and B as ranges to try to use Union on them, but it seems they need to be variants for the
A = Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A:A")
B = Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A:A")

lines to work

This code will list the columns A in SheetA and SheetB in ComboBox1
Sample data as shown below;



Column "A" in SheetA
Column "A" in SheetB




a1
b1


a2
b2


a3
b3


a4
b4


a5
b5


a6
b6


a7
b7


a8
b8


a9
b9


a10
b10


a11
b11


a12
b12


a13
b13


a14



a15



a16



a17




.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim arr1, arr2, arr3
    
    arr1 = Application.Transpose(Sheets("SheetA").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("SheetA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
    arr2 = Application.Transpose(Sheets("SheetB").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("SheetB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
    
    arr3 = Split(Join(arr1, ",") & "," & Join(arr2, ","), ",")
    
    ComboBox1.List = arr3
End Sub

.


This has done exactly what I needed it to do! Thanks. It also has the added bonus of being able to ignore the title (first cell in a column) by starting the range at A2. Now excuse me as I go edit all the other poorly set up lists I have with this newfound information

I have noticed a strange error with the code. Whenever there is only one row of data in a sheet/column, it returns a run time error 13. This doesn´t happen if there is no data at all or 2 or more rows. Only when one value is there. Is there a way around this error?

This is why because an array must have at least 2 elements

Thank you for the answer. I found a code that forces an array with one element to exist instead of throw an error. The code works now even for 1 element lists link
